# Upload folders Asp Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Как организовать загрузку папок в ASP NET MVC?

Для загрузки файлов использую плагин *jquery file upload*. Но когда пытаюсь загрузить папку у меня загружаются только файлы из этой папки и все.
Контроллер

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file, )
    {
        if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/files"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
            }


        return Json(file);
    }
```

Представление

```
<input  type="file" name="file" id="File" multiple>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#File').fileupload({
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '/Progress/Index',
            dropZone: $('#dropzone')
        }).on('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('.progress .progress-bar').css('width', progress + '%');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Вам следует передавать на сервер иерархию файлов и папок, которые вы хотите видеть, и создавать их "руками". Автоматически не получится

Comment: Для такого рода операций существует FTP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery File Upload, несмотря на свою популярность, поддерживает довольно мало сценариев работы. Мне однажды пришлось полностью переписать его из-за нескольких мелочей.

Могу посоветовать вам посмотреть несколько вещей.

1. Как JQuery File Upload ведет себя на клиенте? Посмотрите в отладчике - возможно, можно получить какую-нибудь дополнительную информацию клиентским скриптом.
2. Какие запросы он отправляет на сервер? Возможно, можно выцепить несколько больше информации на стороне сервера, если работать с данными POST напрямую.

---

Нужны ли вам пустые папки? Если нет - то попробуйте посмотреть на относительные пути файлов. Если таковые есть - то можно просто делать `Directory.Create` перед каждым сохранением файла.

---

Обязательно проверьте настройки веб-сервера! Что будет, если кто-то загрузит файл с расширением `.aspx` или `.cshtml`? Папка для хранения загружаемых файлов не должна содержать никаких лишних обработчиков!

Кстати, что будет, если кто-нибудь загрузит вам `web.config`?